# Alert when a query in SQL Server finished running

Tags: sql-server-2008, notifications

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Is there a way to create some sort of an alert (such as an email or a sound) when a long query has finished running?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a SQL Server Agent job out of it, and then in the job properties you can set to notify upon completion/success/failure of said job.  The notification can be an email.

You can do this through SSMS's GUI or through T-SQL.